# Gamemaker - Maintain relative position between objects during rotation

Tags: game-maker

I have a large object and a small object - the small object updates its `x` and `y` position every step to match the `x` and `y` of the larger object. It is easy to keep it in the same position on the larger object without any rotation, as follows (in this instance, slightly above and to the right of the centre of the larger object, here called `Owner`:

```
x = Owner.x + 50
y = Owner.y - 50
```

However, this all goes pearshaped if the larger object is rotated from its sprite's initial position!

How can I maintain the relative position of the two objects even when rotated?

Comment: Not that I am the right person to advice in specifi Game-maker coding, but it would be likely helpful to see the part of the code where you are doing the rotation.

Comment: it's not a step-based rotation; it only occurs once, when the large object is created. It is a random(360) rotation, so the sprite (and therefore the part which I want to bind the smaller object to) changes each time it is spawned, but not again after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `lengthdir_x` and `lengthdir_y` [functions](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/maths/real%20valued%20functions/lengthdir_x.html), like:

```
x = owner.x + lengthdir_x(distance, owner.image_angle); // or owner.direction
y = owner.y + lengthdir_y(distance, owner.image_angle);
```

Also see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26311662/1821428) for similar question, with an example and special tool for calculate values.

P.S. And remember that you need do it in `End Step` event, and not simple `Step`

Comment: Thanks Dmi7ry. Could you explain why I need it in an End Step event? I haven't actually had the need to use such an event before.

Comment: Usually we change coords in `Step` event (if doing it manually, like `x+=4;`). Also GMS updates positions after `Step` event finished (and before `Step End` event started)(when used `speed`, `gravity`, etc). For example, if you will do `hspeed = 4;` then you will have position `x` in `Step` and `x+4` in `Step End`. And second object must change position after first object changed, otherwise here will be small lag

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've used the code as above, with the absolute values that I need to position the smaller object in place of the `distance` value (in this case, 34 for `x` and 192 for `y`) and for some reason the `y` value does not work... the smaller object remains in the centre of the larger object's `y`-axis. The `x`-axis does seem to be working correctly, however. Code in next post.

Comment: `x = Owner.x - lengthdir_x(34, Owner.image_angle)`

Comment: `y = Owner.y + lengthdir_y(192, Owner.image_angle)`

Comment: It's not right.It's not delta of each coordinate. Here must be same distance and angle. If you don't know values, you can calculate it like `dist = point_distance(0, 0, delta_x, delta_y); angle = point_direction(0, 0, delta_x, delta_y);`. And usage: `x = Owner.x + lengthdir_x(dist, angle + Owner.image_angle); y = Owner.y + lengthdir_y(dist, angle + Owner.image_angle);`

Comment: Thanks Dmi7ry,  but I'm a bit confused; there doesn't seem to be any such value in Gamemaker as `delta_x` or `delta_y`...

Comment: You need use numbers instead `delta_x` and `delta_y`. See example https://www.dropbox.com/s/2n4run1nby5207b/RelativePosition.gmz?dl=0

Comment: I see! So I use the values of the distance from the sprite's origin? I think the problem was that I wasn't using -34, but rather 34. Your solution works, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about GameMaker, but usually you need to rotate second object with an angle of the first one like this:

```
// Distances between two object are needed
dx = 50;
dy = 50;

// Cosinus and Sinus are needed
cos = Cos(angle);
sin = Sin(angle);

// Calculate rotation
x = cos * dx - sin * dy + Owner.x;
y = cos * dy + sin * dx + Owner.y;
```

---

*You can also check [Wikipedia article about rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29#Two_dimensions).*